# Upload image as a blob to SAP netweaver gateway oData model

Tags: javascript, ajax, odata, blob, sapui5

I'm trying to upload an image captured on my SAPUI5 application to the SAP server through the Gateway oData model using the following approach

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/05/07/upload-images-from-sap-ui5

you can find my piece of code below. (imageData is the canvas object)

```
imageData.toBlob(function(blob){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob); //array buffer

reader.onload = function (evt){ 
 var fileTarget = evt.target.result;


  var oModel =  new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("<server url>") ;

 oModel.refreshSecurityToken(
function(a, b) {
 oModel.oHeaders = {
                  "x-csrf-token" : b.headers["x-csrf-token"],
                  "slug" : notifNum + ",inspectionImage,PNG,N",
                   "Content-Type" : "image/png",                                         
    };
 oModel.create('/<service name>',fileTarget,{
           //merge : true,
           success : function(postData, response){

            var x;
            alert("success");

              },
           error : function(error){
              alert("epic fail")
           }
    });
    }, function(a) {
           successFaultCallBack.apply(context,[a, false]);
        }, false);


}
},"image/png");
```

But when I debug the request on the server, the image content is truncated to 285 characters (typically the image content has 500000 characters). However on the browser i'm able see that the content length is correct (by doing fileTarget.byteLength before oModel.create method). 
What am i missing here?

Comment: What data type did you set in the gateway service for the image field?

Comment: The data type is xstring.

Comment: I mean in the gateway service. The [EDM primitive type](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_gateway20sp08/helpdata/en/d2/6d93525a324d27e10000000a441470/content.htm)